# StatsModels OLS regression fails to .predict() if any columns in the original data were NaN

Tags: python, pandas, null, regression, nan

It appears that if any of the values in the original data used to fit an OLS model are `NaN`, then running `lm.predict` later will raise the following error:

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'design_info'
```

Reproducible code is below.

Are there preferred best practices for getting around this error, other than simply dropping all of the rows with any `NaN` data from the initial pandas dataframe?

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

df = pd.DataFrame({"y":[x for x in range(10)],
                   "x1":[(x*5 + random.random() * 2) for x in range(10)],
                    "x2":[(x*2.1 + random.random()) for x in range(10)]})

df['x1'][3] = None

formula_string = "y ~ x1 + x2"

lm = smf.ols(formula=formula_string, data=df).fit()
print(lm.summary())
print(lm.fittedvalues)

# this fails
try:
    print(lm.predict(df))
except AttributeError as e:
    print("lm.predict(df) failed: " + str(e))

# this also fails
df2 = df.dropna(how="any")
try:
    print(lm.predict(df2))
except AttributeError as e:
    print("lm.predict(df2) failed: " + str(e))

# this works:
lm2 = smf.ols(formula=formula_string, data=df2).fit()
print(lm2.summary())
print(lm2.fittedvalues)
print(lm2.predict(df2))
```

Comment: This worked for me.  What versions are you using?  I have `pandas 0.16.2` and `statsmodels 0.5.0`

Comment: This works with statsmodels master, and was fixed some time ago. As far as I remember, there were some bugs/inconsistencies in the interaction between patsy (formula) and statsmodels in the missing value handling in statsmodels 0.6.

Comment: Interesting. I'm currently using `statsmodels 0.6.1`, `pandas 0.16.2`, and `patsy 0.4.0` according to `pip freeze`...

Comment: @user333700: do you remember where  the fix was in the code/commits that was "fixed some time ago"?

Comment: Based on the error that you show, this is the same as https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2171 which was fixed among related issues in pull request 2173